# Unused interface reference is not destroyed

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-2010

i had another bug in my app caused by careless usage of Delphi interfaces. When i pass an interface to a procedure which ignores that argument, the instance is never freed. See the following simple example:

```
ITest = interface
    procedure Test;
end;

Tester = class(TInterfacedObject, ITest)
public
    procedure Test;
end;

Base = class
public
    procedure UseTestOrNot(test : ITest); virtual; abstract;
end;

A = class(Base)
public
    procedure UseTestOrNot(test : ITest); override;
end;

B = class(Base)
public
    procedure UseTestOrNot(test : ITest); override;
end;

{ A }

procedure A.UseTestOrNot(test: ITest);
begin
    test.Test();
end;

{ B }

procedure B.UseTestOrNot(test: ITest);
begin
    WriteLn('No test here');
end;

// -------- Test ---------------------------------------
var
    list : TObjectList<Base>;
    x : Base;
    t : ITest;
begin
    ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;

    list := TObjectList<Base>.Create;
    list.Add(A.Create);
    list.Add(B.Create);

    // 1 x Tester leak for each B in list:
    for x in list do
        x.UseTestOrNot(Tester.Create);

    // this is ok
    for x in list do
    begin
        t := Tester.Create;
        x.UseTestOrNot(t);
    end;

    list.Free;
end.
```

Can you please explain what goes wrong with the reference counter?
Can you give any best practice/ guideline (like "Never create an interfaced instance inside a function call [if you don't know what happens inside]).

The best solution i can think of for this example is to write a template method in class Base that saves the passed test instance and calls an abstract `DoUseTestOrNot` method.

**EDIT**
Delphi 2010

Comment: What version of Delphi is this?

Comment: Does not matter, it is a bug regardless of version. wait until delphi ex 2? Cheers

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=75036 http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=71015

Comment: @kibab: those reports are for `const` parameters, this is for a regular parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>It is a different manifestation of the bugs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509015/should-the-compiler-hint-warn-when-passing-object-instances-directly-as-const-int).

I will add this to the QC report.</strike>

This does not reproduce in Delphi XE update 1 any more.

--jeroen

Comment: For regression: can you mail me a fully functional console program (.dpr) showing the memory leak in Delphi 2010 - preferably with FastMM? Anything at pluimers dot com works, just start with my first name. That way I can rule out any typos I made from making your above code compile.

Answer (score 8):

Add a guid to you ITest declaration

```
ITest = interface
['{DB6637F9-FAD3-4765-9EC1-0A374AAC7469}']
    procedure Test;
end;
```

Change the loop to this

```
for x in list do
    x.UseTestOrNot(Tester.Create as ITest);
```

The GUID is neccesary to be able to use `as`

`Test.Create as ITest` makes the compiler to add the release where the created object goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank your for this workaround. Is there any menu entry or button to insert the GUID? I always forget the shortcut, as i never use GUIDs (i always try to avoid as and is etc).