# How to trace _AddRef / _Release calls for OLE Automation objects

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ole

(Delphi XE2 update 4)

I'm trying to get a big Microsoft Word OLE automation unit I inherited (based on the early binding  [TWordApplication](https://www.google.com/search?q=Delphi%20TWordApplication) and interfaces from the `WordXP`/`Word2010` units) to close `WINWORD.EXE` when all references have been released.

So far, it looks like I did catch a couple of reference leaks: most references are properties or local variables.

Some usage scenario's however still keep `WINWORD.EXE` open.

A few of the fixes indicate I should favour local variables in stead of chains from

```
procedure TOffice_10_XP_WordInterface.AddDocument;
var
  WordApplicationDocuments: Documents;
begin
  WordApplication_Documents.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
end;
```

to

```
procedure TOffice_10_XP_WordInterface.AddDocument;
var
  WordApplicationDocuments: Documents;
begin
  WordApplicationDocuments := WordApplication_Documents;
  WordApplicationDocuments.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
end;
```

based on a WordApplication_Documents property that calls this function:

```
function TOffice_10_XP_WordInterface.GetWordApplication_Documents: Documents;
begin
  Result := WordApplicationReference.Documents;
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise EAccessViolation.Create('Documents');
end;
```

The properties are there to make the [EAccessViolation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.EAccessViolation) messages more readable than the $C0000005 errors you get in the debugger.

I'm wondering about generic (since I'll probably need this for other automation projects as well) ways to monitor [_AddRef](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IInterface._AddRef) and [_Release](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IInterface._Release) calls.

I did take a look at these links:

- [Understanding and correcting interface reference leaks in Delphi's Vcl.OleCtrls.pas](http://marc.durdin.net/2012/07/understanding-and-correcting-interface.html) (it does not apply as I don't use the [TOleControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.OleCtrls.TOleControl) based interface)
- [How to Find a Missing _Release](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2011/12/how-to-find-missing-release.html) (that's what I use until now)
- [Should the compiler hint/warn when passing object instances directly as const interface parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509015/should-the-compiler-hint-warn-when-passing-object-instances-directly-as-const-in) (does not apply: no const parameters that take these interfaces)
- [Unused interface reference is not destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681285/unused-interface-reference-is-not-destroyed) (fixed in Delphi XE update 1 and above)
- [WinWord.exe won't quit after calling Word.Documents.Add - Word .NET Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511464/winword-exe-wont-quit-after-calling-word-documents-add-word-net-interop)
- [Is COM broken in XE2, and how might I work around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886116/is-com-broken-in-xe2-and-how-might-i-work-around-it) (fixed in Delphi XE2 update 2)

Comment: Going to be a little tricky. The COM server is out of proc and so the code you want to instrument is in a different process.

Comment: I was hoping there was a smart way to break on the local proxy.

Comment: You can do that but it's only part of the story. References will be taken in the other process.

Comment: Anyway, there must be COM debugging tools. Does WinDbg understand COM? I'd expect any such tools to be MS centric. If you use map2dbg you can get WinDbg to understand your symbols.

Answer (score 1):

A tedious way that gets you going is this:

Put breakpoints of all `_AddRef` and `_Release` calls in the Delphi `System` unit that are not inside `TInterfacedObject` specific methods.

Now eliminate (using conditional expressions) all the interfaces that are not part of Delphi (`EAX` contains the `vTable` pointer for each interface).

1. Start debugging your application with a simple run/exit without doing much actual functionality:
2. Before tracing in each call, make a note of the `EAX` value.
3. If you end up in any of these methods: `NopRelease`, `NopAddref`, `TInterfacedObject._AddRef`, `TInterfacedObject._Release`, `MemRelease`, `MemAddRef` then add the `EAX` value to a conditional breakpoint instruction for all of the breakpoints like below.

Example conditional breakpoint expression for my application:

```
(EAX <> $401E58) and (EAX <> $54AD14) and (EAX <> $4A7C88) ...
```

This method has a lot of drawbacks, but it gets you going.

Drawbacks:

- There are limitations on the length of the conditional breakpoint expression. Which means that if you continue to add `and (EXA <> $xxxx)` portions, the debugger will ignore those without indicating a warning.
- You loose the setting if you exit Delphi without saving your desktop
- It takes a lot of time to setup

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `EAX` has the interface reference in each method. Basically you want to eliminate all interface references that are not COM references.