# Why is this interface delegation causing memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, freepascal

Suppose I have following codes

Unit **TalkerIntf.pas**

```
unit TalkerIntf;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}

type

    ITalker = interface
        ['{95E1FAE3-7495-4404-AE88-6A7DB88383EC}']
        procedure say() ;
    end;

implementation
end.
```

Unit **TalkerImpl.pas**

```
unit TalkerImpl;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}

uses

    TalkerIntf;

type

    TTalker = class(TInterfacedObject, ITalker)
    public
        procedure say();
    end;

implementation

    procedure TTalker.say();
    begin
        writeln('Hello');
    end;

end.
```

Unit **DelegateTalkerImpl.pas**

```
unit DelegateTalkerImpl;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}

uses

    TalkerIntf;

type

    TDelegateTalker = class(TInterfacedObject, ITalker)
    private
        fActualTalker : ITalker;
    public
        constructor create(const talker : ITalker);
        destructor destroy(); override;

        property talker : ITalker read fActualTalker implements ITalker;
    end;

implementation

    constructor TDelegateTalker.create(const talker : ITalker);
    begin
        fActualTalker := talker;
    end;

    destructor TDelegateTalker.destroy();
    begin
        fActualTalker := nil;
        inherited destroy();
    end;

end.
```

and program **memleak.pas**

```
program memleak;

{$MODE OBJFPC}

uses

    TalkerIntf,
    TalkerImpl,
    DelegateTalkerImpl;

var
    talker : ITalker;

begin
    talker := TDelegateTalker.create(TTalker.create());
    talker.say();
end.
```

Compiling with FreePascal 3.0.4 and heaptrc on (`-gh`), heaptrc reports there are memory leak

```
$ fpc -gh memleak.pas
$ ./memleak
```

Heaptrc output

```
Hello
Heap dump by heaptrc unit
2 memory blocks allocated : 64/64
0 memory blocks freed     : 0/0
2 unfreed memory blocks : 64
True heap size : 32768
True free heap : 32384
Should be : 32448
Call trace for block $00007FA0D7846180 size 32
$000000000040020F
Call trace for block $00007FA0D78460C0 size 32
```

Why is this interface delegation causing memory leak? How to avoid it?

[Original post](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,46575.0.html)

**Update**

It seems the only workaround is remove `implements` and do delegation manually. Following code does not suffer from memory leak.

```
unit DelegateTalkerImpl;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}

uses

    TalkerIntf;

type

    TDelegateTalker = class(TInterfacedObject, ITalker)
    private
        fActualTalker : ITalker;
    public
        constructor create(const talker : ITalker);
        destructor destroy(); override;

        procedure say();
    end;

implementation

    constructor TDelegateTalker.create(const talker : ITalker);
    begin
        fActualTalker := talker;
    end;

    destructor TDelegateTalker.destroy();
    begin
        fActualTalker := nil;
        inherited destroy();
    end;

    procedure TDelegateTalker.say();
    begin
        fActualTalker.say();
    end;
end.
```

Comment: I think that this is a case of fpc copying a long standing Delphi bug which it seems will never ever be fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028266/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640841/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846335/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ASerge's comment](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,46575.msg332380.html#msg332380)

> When you define a variable as ITalker, the newly created object is not returned, but only the field that implements it. As a result, a newly created object is leaked.
>   Delphi's behavior is the same.

To avoid memory leak but still using `implements` keyword, we need to assign to temporary variable of type other than `ITalker` and then typecast it to `ITalker`.

```
var
    talker : ITalker;
    delegateTalker : IInterface;

begin
    delegateTalker := TDelegateTalker.create(TTalker.create());
    talker := delegateTalker as ITalker;
    talker.say();
end.
```